# Display entire contents of an iframe without scrolling

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to display the entire contents of the iframe so that there is only the default browser scroll bar. I can not seem to get rid of the iframe verticle scroll bar. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#content{

 min-height: 100vh;
color:#1b1b1b; /*-light black-*/
font-size: 1.1em;
background-color:#f2f0ea;/* --off- yellow-white-- */
padding:1%;
border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
<head>
<html lang = "en">
<body>
    <div style="content">
        <iframe style="overflow:hidden; position: float; display:block;  min-height: 100vh;  background-color: #f2f0ea; border: none;" 
                src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3-ogIreQhm-aHutOfKjDI17buwCJRrkzmwvQGMafGw/pub?embedded=true" 
                height=100% width=100%></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, your code is working I can see vertical scroll bar in chrome,IE and Firefox So what is the problem with you ?

Comment: I do not want the scroll bar. I want the entire contents of the iframe to show up that I can see with the browser scroll.

Comment: @SarangaR are you in control of the iframe source? Each image in that googleDocs link has `overflow: hidden`. My demo shows an iframe with a normal page for `src` http://plnkr.co/edit/EFP750Fth4PTutwdK56Y?p=preview

Comment: I have added the code here so you can see what the problem is more clearly. http://plnkr.co/edit/rU6BIcKUkTzFksTuneuh?p=streamer   The height of the document is dynamic and I want the div and iframe to expand to the height of the google document in the iframe so that no inner scroll is needed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#content{

 min-height: 100vh;
color:#1b1b1b; /*-light black-*/
font-size: 1.1em;
background-color:#f2f0ea;/* --off- yellow-white-- */
padding:1%;
border-radius:5px;
}

</style>
<head>
<html lang = "en">
<body>
    <div style="content">
        <iframe style="overflow:hidden; position: absolute; display:block;  min-height: 100vh;  background-color: #f2f0ea; border: none;" 
                src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3-ogIreQhm-aHutOfKjDI17buwCJRrkzmwvQGMafGw/pub?embedded=true" 
                height=600%; width=100%  scrolling="no" ></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes the page too long on short content. It extends beyond the divs.

Comment: @user1854438 if your content has fixed height this is okay

Comment: The height is dynamic because the data comes from a google doc

Answer (score 1):

The googleDocs link in the iframe's `src` has every image with this: `overflow: hidden` I made a demo with normal content. Although it's the iframe's content that has the scrollbar, it's hard to tell since the parent page has no scrollbars.

There were a ton of syntax errors here's a few:

- `<div style="content">` what you really meant was: `<div id="content">`
- `position: float;` I'm not sure if you intended one or the other.
- `<head>
    <html lang = "en">`

  Given the position and content of these two elements, The `<head>` is actually the closing tag `</head>` and the `<html lang="en">` should be at the very top of the page.

Here's the demo with normal content: http://plnkr.co/edit/EFP750Fth4PTutwdK56Y?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for correcting the error and giving me a demo version. I am anxious to try this out with the div content when get home.

Comment: My pleasure, sir. I think it's the first typo that slowed you down a bit. Sometimes things like that plague me for hours and I'll need someone else to look at it with fresh eyes.

Comment: Your fix works almost. There is an oddball issue where the it almost works, but does not actually go all the way to the end of the document. I'll post the code to plnker tonight. Can you possibly take a look at it?

Comment: Sure I can, no problem.

Comment: Thank you http://plnkr.co/edit/rU6BIcKUkTzFksTuneuh?p=preview
  I think I'll need the url after your edits in order to see the changes?

Comment: @user1854438 I reviewed the plunk with Chrome and Firefox PC and I am reaching the end of content, I think. The last line is: *Testing a long path* Do you use a Mac? If so, have which browsers are you using? If this is a phone issue, you'll have to wait until tomorrow, i forgot my iPhone and left at work.

Comment: Can I get the url to the plunker you updated? I get to the botton with the inner scrollbar only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103153/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-user1854438).